# File System missing in Local Group Policy Editor

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I'm trying to manage some folder permissions in my computer.
I need to use `Computer Configuration/Windows Settings/Security Settings/File System`,
as described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756952(v=ws.10).aspx) or [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/d2b1920f-c671-4507-b847-5829421454bc/c-systemdrive-lockdown-using-group-policy#answers), but
I can't find `File System` in the Local Group Policy Editor tree.

This is a picture that I found around the web, that shows the tree including `File System`

[image]

and this is a picture from my PC WITHOUT `File System` in the tree

[image: two]

Why is the `File System` missing??